# Why use exec to read from another file instead of importing it?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first post on stack overflow so excuse me in case this is a naive. I have two files, file1.py and file2.py.

file1.py just has an array(lets name it foo), which i want to include in file2. So far, I have been doing this simply by importing like this (in file2):

```
from file1 import foo
```

I stumbled upon another way to do this using exec(), but I am not sure why this would be better/faster/more efficient.

```
def readFromFile():
    data = dict()
    with open("file1.py") as file:
        exec(file.read(), data)
    return data['foo']
```

So here are my two questions:

1) Why would someone prefer the second way?

2) why is foo stored in the data dictionary but not in locals() of readFromFile

Answer (score 0):

1): You usually wouldn't prefer the `exec` way, but for local imports (in the same directory) there is not too much difference

2): Because the second argument `data` in `exec(file.read(), data)` specifies to put everything into the `data` dict.